# Projective embeddings of quotients of normal varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a normal complex projective variety of dimension $m$, $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$, and $Y = X / G$ be the quotient. I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ is a normal rational surface (not just smooth). My question is fundamentally about degrees of projective embeddings of $X$ and $Y$, though I want to state it in slightly different language. I would expect an answer to be in the literature somewhere, since the question seems basic, but my search has only found related but ultimately irrelevant work.

Consider a flat, finite map $\Phi : X \to \mathbb{P}^N$ whose image is not contained in a proper linear subspace. Basically, $\Phi$ is a projective holomorphic immersion with $N$ chosen optimally. Given a $(1,1)$-form $\omega$ on $X$ representing a "good" orbifold Kähler metric (it suffices in my setting to assume it is a positive real multiple of the first Chern class of some ample line bundle), we can define:
$$
\mathrm{Vol}(X, \omega, \Phi) = \int_X \Phi^*(\sigma_N) \wedge \omega^{m-1}
$$
where $\sigma_N$ is the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{P}^N$. We then can define the *$N$-dimensional projective volume* $\mathrm{Vol}_N(X, \omega)$ to be $\infty$ if no such $\Phi$ exists and
$$
\mathrm{Vol}_N(X, \omega) = \inf_{\Phi : X \to \mathbb{P}^N} \mathrm{Vol}(X, \omega, \Phi)
$$
otherwise. Note that this is finite for sufficiently large $N$. One can then define the *projective volume*
$$
\mathrm{Vol}(X, \omega) = \liminf_{N \to \infty} \mathrm{Vol}_N(X, \omega) \ge 0.
$$
My interest is in how this quantity behaves under finite quotients.

Assume that $\omega$ is $G$-invariant, descending to $\omega_Y$ on $Y$ (my group $G$ acts by isometries of the orbifold Kähler metric). It is not hard to show that
$$
\mathrm{Vol}(X, \omega) \le |G| \mathrm{Vol}(Y, \omega_Y)
$$
using compositions $X \to Y \to \mathbb{P}^N$. The above assumptions imply that the map $X \to Y$ is étale over Zariski open submanifolds of each, hence it's just the degree formula from differential topology.

> **Main question:** What about a bound in the other direction? More specifically, is it true that
>   $$
> \frac{1}{|G|}\mathrm{Vol}(Y, \omega_Y) \le \mathrm{Vol}(X, \omega)?
> $$
>   If not, is it at least the case that
>   $$
> \frac{1}{p(|G|)}\mathrm{Vol}(Y, \omega_Y) \le \mathrm{Vol}(X, \omega)
> $$
>   for some polynomial $p$, say, depending only on $m = \mathrm{dim(X)}$ or the assumption that $X$ is a normal rational surface?

This is at heart a question about degrees of projective embeddings of $Y$ induced by projective embeddings of $X$. I think one can show $p(|G|) = |G|!$ works, but I would really like a better bound if possible. Some weakenings:

> **Question 2:** If Question 1 has a negative answer in general, is there an assumption on $G$ that can ensure a yes answer? For instance, what if $G$ is solvable? What if $G$ contains an abelian subgroup of index at most $N$ for some fixed $N \ge 0$?

Note that the solvable case reduces by induction to the case where $G$ is cyclic. The last part of Question 2 comes from the fact that if $X$ is a normal rational surface, then $G$ can be realized as a finite subgroup of the Cremona group $\mathrm{Cr}(2)$, and all finite subgroups of the Cremona group are known to have an abelian subgroup of uniformly bounded index.

Any references or general insight would be greatly appreciated.